# Where did 42 come from in the programming world?

Tags: random

I see `42` used **A LOT** in the programming world as examples.  In screencasts, tutorials, etc.

Where did the popularity of this number come from?

Comment: This is almost, but not quite, entirely off topic.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42

Comment: Douglas Adams.  42 always has and always will be there.  It is the answer.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx no, never.  Please educate me.

Comment: @cbmeeks, my sarcasm was uncalled for, but if you had mentioned that you googled the number 42 and still couldn't answer your question, I wouldn't have said it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is from the book *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) has more detail:

> In [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy], a group of hyper-intelligent pan-dimensional beings demand to learn the Ultimate Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything from the supercomputer, Deep Thought, specially built for this purpose. It takes Deep Thought 7½ million years to compute and check the answer, which turns out to be 42. The Ultimate Question itself is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to read [The Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference to [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

Answer (score 2):

It's the [answer](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything&cp=46&qe=dGhlIGFuc3dlciB0byBsaWZlIHRoZSB1bml2ZXJzZSBhbmQgZXZlcnl0aGluZw&qesig=UIXRTTycd4XJSNELX-nf0g&pkc=AFgZ2tmiecIJI-NqQdvOmxwbk5C9TAIBQm1J2-NccpT4QHyrUnHshqR_qEyNQp1vZ3pSH59aOWVYdvLARYyRBXPrpvFfjG7dzg&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=951dc7972bfd90fb&biw=1680&bih=907).

Answer (score 1):

Douglas Adams came up with it and as mentioned it's a reference to THGTTG.  Back in the day, programmers were more "geeky" than they are now.  Generally they were math geeks.  Being extremely geeky would put you in line with Douglas Adams' books.  If you look for it, you'll find it everywhere.  Where did I put my towel?